# vectors in python structs

Tags: c++, python

is there a way to store vectors in structs in python? specifically, im trying to do:

```
struct data{
   string name           // name of event 
   string location       // location of event
   vector <int> times    // times the event happens in 24 hour format
};
```

im not sure how to do it with the structs module, since ive never used it before. will creating a class do it better?

Comment: Do you want to construct and pass one of these structures to C++ from Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear from your question, but if you just want a similar structure in Python you can use a `list` in place of the `vector<int>`.

```
data = ('John','Los Angeles, CA',[1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

Another alternative is to use a [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html?highlight=namedtuple#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields):

```
>>> import collections
>>> Data = collections.namedtuple('Data','name location times')
>>> data = Data('John','Los Angeles',[1,2,3,4])
>>> data.name
'John'
>>> data.location
'Los Angeles'
>>> data.times
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> data.times[0]
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Python's struct module cannot deal with `std::vector`, which has an implementation-defined internal structure. You will need to provide some kind of wrapping (e.g., [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html) or [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/python/doc/index.html)) to expose this structure to Python.